# How to get all orders and all invoices from php in Magento?

Tags: magento

How do I programmatically access all orders and all invoices from php in Magento?

Comment: You should ask more specifically

Answer (score 24):

```
<?php
require_once("app/Mage.php");
$app = Mage::app('');

$salesModel=Mage::getModel("sales/order");
$salesCollection = $salesModel->getCollection();
foreach($salesCollection as $order)
{
    $orderId= $order->getIncrementId();
    echo $orderId;
}
?>
```